# Bitmap rendered only after refresh or not rendered at all

Tags: javascript, bitmap, easeljs

I implemented a grid consisting of cells using createjs:

```
function Cell(identifier,color,gridPositionVector,canvasPositionVector,width)
{
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.color = color;
    this.gridPositionVector = gridPositionVector;
    this.canvasPositionVector = canvasPositionVector;
    this.width = width;

    var square = new createjs.Shape();
    square.graphics.beginFill(color).drawRect(0, 0, width, width);
    square.x = this.canvasPositionVector.X();
    square.y = this.canvasPositionVector.Y();
    square.name = "square";
    stage.addChild(square);
    stage.update();

}

Cell.prototype.GetGridPositionVector = function () { return this.gridPositionVector; };

function Vector2(x,y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Vector2.prototype.X = function () { return this.x; };
Vector2.prototype.Y = function () { return this.y; };

function Grid()
{
    this.cellArray = [];
    this.gridArray = [   ['o', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'x'],
                         ['x', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
                         ['x', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'x']];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.gridArray.length; i++) {
        var row = this.gridArray[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            switch (row[j]) {
                case 'o':
                    var cell = new Cell('o', 'green', new Vector2(i, j), new Vector2(j * cellWidth, i * cellWidth), cellWidth); 
                    this.cellArray.push(cell);
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    var cell = new Cell('o', 'blue', new Vector2(i, j), new Vector2(j * cellWidth, i * cellWidth), cellWidth); 
                    this.cellArray.push(cell);
                default:

            }
        }
    }
}

Grid.prototype.GetGridArray = function () {
    return this.gridArray;
}
```

I also implemented a Creep.js which displays an image:

```
function Creep(id, gridPositionVector, texture)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.texture = texture;

    this.texture.x = gridPositionVector.X() * 50;
    this.texture.y = gridPositionVector.Y() * 50;

    stage.addChild(this.texture);
    stage.update();
    console.log('creep created and added.');
}
```

In my init function (called onLoad) I am calling everything that is needed to display the grid and the creep.

```
var stage;

var cellWidth = 50;

function init()
{
    stage = new createjs.Stage("DisplayCanvas");
    // to get onMouseOver & onMouseOut events, we need to enable them on the stage:
    stage.enableMouseOver();

    var cellGrid = new Grid();

    var creepTex = new createjs.Bitmap("creep.png");
    console.log(creepTex.id);

    var creep = new Creep('creep1', new Vector2(9, 9), creepTex);
}
```

So far everything is displayed as it should. Then I checked the project in in my TFS-project. After I downloaded the latest version on another machine the following problem occurs:

1. The creep image is not displayed anymore.
2. I tried debugging and logging, everything seems to work right.
3. I also tried to call the image directly with `http://localhost:59271/creep.png`. The image is found and being displayed in the browser.
4. If I run the project in Firefox the image is not displayed. Only if I refresh the page it suddenly appears. This works in Firefox only. In IE10 and Chrome it is not displayed even after refresh or clearing cache.

This is a mystery to me because on my other developer machine everything works fine and the creep image is displayed as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an image using a string path, it has to create and load an image in the background. Even if it is cached in the browser, it will not be available *immediately*. You can get around this by:

1. Listening for a load on the image, and updating the stage
2. Updating the stage constantly (it will show up once it is ready)
3. Preloading your content, with something like [PreloadJS](http://createjs.com/preloadjs/), and passing an image *reference* to the Bitmap.

Here is the simplest approach:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    stage.update();
}
img.src = "creep.png";
var creepTex = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: solved the issue by adding a tick function to the stage and updating it constantly.